# coldfusion output to JSON

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, lucee

I have the cfoutput query with group attribute, all is good, but i want to convert that into nested JSON output , a kind of ul > li

but I am stuck with how I am trying to output it, Here is my try so far

```
<cfset dataArray = ArrayNew(1) />
<cfoutput query="a" group="ID">
    <cfoutput>
        <cfset dataStruct = StructNew() >
        <cfset dataStruct["Name"] = a.name>
        <cfset dataStruct["WebUrl"] = a.WebUrl>
        <cfset dataStruct["ID"] = a.ID>
        <cfset dataStruct["Name"] = a.Name>
        <cfset dataStruct["Program"] = a.Program>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(dataArray,dataStruct) />
    </cfoutput>    
</cfoutput>
<cfdump var="#dataArray#" abort>
```

which is yielding me incorrect results, because one ID can have 10 programs underneath it,

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to serialize it.

```
 <cfset JSONString = serializejson(dataArray)>

 <cfoutput>#JSONString#</cfoutput>
```

**Off topic**

I would use newer syntax for this. Note that you are not really outputtiing when you are looping. `<cfloop>` is more appropriate.

```
 <cfset dataArray = [] />
 <cfloop query="a" group="ID">
     <cfloop>
         <cfscript> 
         dataStruct = {};
         dataStruct["Name"] = a.name;
         dataStruct["WebUrl"] = a.WebUrl;
         dataStruct["ID"] = a.ID;
         dataStruct["Name"] = a.Name;
         dataStruct["Program"] = a.Program;
         dataArray.append(dataStruct);
         <cfscript> 
     </cfloop>    
 </cfloop>



 <cfset JSONString = serializejson(dataArray)>

 <cfoutput>#JSONString#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score -2):

What I would do is make `dataStruct.Program` an array and do the inner loop there.

```
<cfset dataArray = ArrayNew(1) />
<cfoutput query="a" group="ID">
    <cfset dataStruct = StructNew() >
    <cfset dataStruct["Name"] = a.name>
    <cfset dataStruct["WebUrl"] = a.WebUrl>
    <cfset dataStruct["ID"] = a.ID>
    <cfset dataStruct["Name"] = a.Name>
    <cfset dataStruct["Program"] = []>
    <cfoutput>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(dataStruct["Program"], a.Program)>
    </cfoutput>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(dataArray,dataStruct) />
<cfoutput>
<cfdump var="#dataArray#" abort>
```

Then you just serialize it to JSON. This assumes `a.Program` is a string or a number; if it is more complex than that, you may need another struct there.

Comment: i think we are missing a point here, basically it should have an output like this: `<cfoutput query = "a" group = "Id" ><ul id="List"><li><h3><cfswitch expression="#Id#">
<cfcase value="1">Program1</cfcase><cfcase value = "2">    Program2
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value = "3">
     Program3 
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value = "4">
     Program4
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value = "5">
     Program5
    </cfcase>
    <cfdefaultcase></cfdefaultcase>
   </cfswitch>
  </h3></li>
 <cfoutput>
  <li><a href="/#WebUrl#">#Program#</a></li>
 </cfoutput>
 </ul>
</cfoutput>`

Comment: we are almost there but with few exceptions

Comment: I don't understand that structure. What does the ID have to do with the programs? you described it differently in your question, stating that each id could have as many as 10 programs. The code in your comment above instead presents 1 program per id, based on the id column rather than the program column. At that point, what is the group for?

Comment: The Group is the ID of which is referred to this one `<cfset dataStruct["ID"] = a.ID>` : The main criteria is the user can search for a degreeID which i would say is: 3, that will get all the results based upon the degreeid = 3 which will bring all programnames and those programe names need to be segregated further based upon what type of course it is

Comment: @JJK, all these things you are bringing up should have been a part of the original question. And I am confused why you are even using JSON.